# jQuery UI dialog overlay - how to set different background colors for different dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have used different jQuery dialogs. For some dialogs I want a transparent background.
If I change the `background` CSS in the `.ui-widget-overlay` class then it will apply to all the dialogs.

How to set different background colors for different dialogs?

Answer (score 4):

Just create a style like the following and use the `dialogClass` option on those dialogs you want to have a transparent background. Of course you can make multiple styles and pass in whatever you want

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .transparent { background:transparent }
</style>

//make dialog with transparent background
$("#dialog").dialog({dialogClass:'transparent'});
//make default dialog
$("#dialog2").dialog();
```

Check demo site: http://jsbin.com/ifoja (basic jquery, jquery ui, jquery ui css + custom css transparent class)

Answer (score 3):

There is only one overlay for all jQuery widgets. Therefor we have to change it's opacity on demand:

```
var overlayOpacityNormal = 0.3, overlayOpacitySpecial = 0;
$('#idOfDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function()
    {
        overlayOpacityNormal = $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('opacity');
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('opacity', overlayOpacitySpecial);
    },
    beforeClose: function()
    {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('opacity', overlayOpacityNormal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you set the !important keyword:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .transparent { background:transparent !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below code but it still taking the background of class `.ui-widget-overlay`

```
$("#dialog_empty").dialog({     
    dialogClass:'transparent',                    
    resizable: false, 
    draggable: false, 
    modal: true,                
    height: 0, 
    width: 0,
    autoOpen: false,
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0
    }
});
$('#dialog_empty').dialog('open');
$('#dialog_empty').css('display','');
```

Comment: check demo link at end of my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog call, just set modal:false for the dialogs you want transparent.

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to @RonnySherer, but it didn't seem to work in cruddy old IE7 with multiple jQuery UI dialogs. So instead of directly setting the opacity of the overlay element I simply added/removed a CSS class which worked in IE7 in addition to modern browsers.

CSS Class:

```
div.modalOverlaySolid
{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(div#divModalDialog).dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").next(".ui-widget-overlay").addClass("modalOverlayPrivate");
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").next(".ui-widget-overlay").removeClass("modalOverlayPrivate");
    }
});
```