# jQuery dialog background change

Tags: jquery

> Duplicate of
>   [jQuery UI dialog overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886678/jquery-ui-dialog-overlay)

have used different jQuery dialogs. For some dialogs I want a transparent background. If I change the background CSS in the .ui-widget-overlay class then it will apply to all the dialogs.

How to set different background colors for different dialogs?

I wrote the below code but it still taking the background of class ".ui-widget-overlay"

```
$("#dialog_empty").dialog({     
    dialogClass:'transparent',                    
    resizable: false, 
    draggable: false, 
    modal: true,                
    height: 0, 
    width: 0,
    autoOpen: false,
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0
    }
});

$('#dialog_empty').dialog('open');
$('#dialog_empty').css('display','');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the **! important** of css to prioritize your css over that of dialog's original for a given css code. Here is an example:

```
<style>
  .mybg
  background:#ff0000 !important;
</style>
```

Now you need to apply **mybg** class to the dialog.

Comment: Now I've learned something really !important =) Thanks for explaning what this keyword does. I've looked around for about two days now to achieve a jQuery UI Dialog background transparency, and with this, I have been able to achieve it! =)

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code will give all dialogs that have the transparent class set a transparent background, which I believe is what you want.

```
$('.transparent').css('background-color','transparent')
```

You can obviously modify this by replacing transparent by a colour, or replacing the .transparent by another class.