# css background transparent

Tags: css

i need to create a pop up window in css which opens when we click a button or anything else. when that screen was open it should be a transparent one, so that the background text or images to that screen should be a viewable one when it was open(look like glass or mirror)....

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Please clarify

Comment: Sounds like maybe he wants a Lightbox-esque script. Of course, I have no idea either.

Comment: background: transparent;

Comment: for example u look into this site, http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/content_overlay_css/  here if u scroll down the code content will also goes down and at the same time the background image is displayed when the code content is over that image..

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery i use "Dialog" and modified css as below :

.ui-dialog {
      opacity: 0.9;
}

or see [jQuery UI dialog overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886678/jquery-ui-dialog-overlay)

Answer (score 0):

Use a semi-transparent png (including alpha) as the background image of your 'popup'.

```
.popup {
 background-image: url(images/SemiTransparentImageWithAlphaChannel.png);
}
```

Which works pretty much cross-browser (no IE6) and doesn't need CSS3